# How to replace an object with selection?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

In Evil mode, is it possible to prevent change and deletion commands from putting the replaced object into the selection (system clipboard)? I would like yanking to still do so.

I'd like to be able to yank an object (or copy it in another application), then move to the destination, press `cw` to replace it, and press <kbd>Cmd-V</kbd> to paste the source text. The standard behaviour is for all yank, change, and deletion to go to the unnamed register, which is also used for pasting, which means that I have to resort to "`viwp`" or "`cw`<kbd>C-r</kbd> `0`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evil doesn't support this out of the box, but Emacs’ [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) feature will let you get what you want.

Simplifying a lot, `evil-change` calls `evil-delete` and `evil-delete` calls `evil-yank` then `delete-region`.  `delete-region` does not mess with the clipboard, so one solution is to modify what `evil-yank` does within `evil-delete`.  For purposes of this example I’m going to make `evil-yank` a no-op when it’s called from `evil-delete`.  I’m doing this by defining an appropriate wrapper function then using `advice-add` to wrap `evil-delete`.

```
(defun my-yank-is-noop-wrapper (orig-fun &rest args)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'evil-yank) #'ignore))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'evil-delete :around #'my-yank-is-noop-wrapper)
```

You can get more creative with advice.  For instance, you could filter the arguments before they go into `evil-delete` (like, you could check the value of the `register` argument and set it to something.)  For this next example I’m just going to make `evil-delete` message you about its arguments; you can tweak the code to do whatever you want.

```
(defun my-filter-arguments (args)
  (message "Args: %s" args)
  ;; do something to args here
  ;; the advised function sees the result of this function
  ;; so be sure to return an args list
  args)

(advice-add 'evil-delete :filter-args #'my-filter-arguments)
```

Advice can be really hard to debug if it misbehaves, though!  Keep that `advice-remove` handy if things get weird!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by looking at [`evil-change`](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/3d9f76f3add56f670042af9421b36dfb8574ad00/evil-commands.el#L1478) and at [`evil-visual-paste`](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/3d9f76f3add56f670042af9421b36dfb8574ad00/evil-commands.el#L1952) as they explicitly call `evil-delete` (or `evil-delete-line`)